# Acer Predator Helios 300 won't charge and shuts down when unplugged I tried every method in the internet but doesn't work

Tags: laptop, acer

My predator Helios 300 (i7-10 RTX 3060) works only when plugged into the power, though the charge is 98%, which should be ample to run it on battery.

I tried every solution in the internet but it doesn't work (I tried updating the drivers) but nothing works.

Comment: Sounds like a new battery is required.

Comment: I don't think that is the problem. I bought that computer in the last month and It is new.

Comment: Then it should be under warranty. Replace it.

Comment: While you purchased the laptop new, a 10th Intel Core generation mobile processor is more than a year old, since we already have products that have 12th Intel Core generation mobile processors.  If you mean something other than your system having an `Intel Core i7-10750H` you should clarify what processor you have exactly. `Intel Core i7-10750H` was released in Q2'20. *It sounds like your problem is a bad battery and you should take steps to replace it.*